# SSH connection closed by remote host after few seconds of successful login

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, timeout

I am trying to ssh to my AWS Server using pem file. It is able to connect but after few seconds of in-activity it logs out saying "Connection closed by remote host".

I have tried  `-o TCPKeepAlive=true`  also but that is also not helping .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem here was my Internet connection. I was using Jio . Moment I changed it to another internet provider; it worked fine.

Comment: I have faced this issue multiple times. Is there a way around this that you have come across now?

Comment: try changing internet provider.

Comment: seems like no other way around